# Eigenvalue of Linear Transformation of Change of Diagonals

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

for $V = M_{2x2}(R)$ and $T(\begin{matrix}a &b\\c&d\end{matrix}) = (\begin{matrix}d &b\\c&a\end{matrix})$.

How could I find eigen-vectors of T?

Answer (score 0):

$T 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 &\;\; 0 \\
0  & \;\;0
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 0 \\
0  & \;\;1\end{array}
\right]  $

$T 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 1 \\
0  & \;\;0
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 1 \\
0  & \;\;0\end{array}
\right]  $

$T 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 0 \\
1  & \;\;0
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 0 \\
1  & \;\;0\end{array}
\right]  $

$T 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 &\;\; 0 \\
0  & \;\;1
\end{array}
\right] = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 &\;\; 0 \\
0  & \;\;0\end{array}
\right]  $

Then the matrix corresponding to the transformation is,

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then find eigen vector by using  $Ax = \lambda{x}$